# Execute a function on matching pairs in a map

Tags: c++, set, stl-algorithm

I have some code that looks roughly like this; given two maps, if the `first` key exists in both maps, then multiply the two `second` values together, then sum all the products. For example:

```
s1 = {{1, 2.5}, {2, 10.0}, {3, 0.5}};
s2 = {{1, 10.0},           {3, 20.0}, {4, 3.33}};
```

The answer should be `2.5*10.0 + 0.5*20.0`, the sum of the products of the matching keys.

```
double calcProduct(std::map<int, double> const &s1, std::map<int, double> const &s2)
{
    auto s1_it = s1.begin();
    auto s2_it = s2.begin();

    double result = 0;
    while (s1_it != s1.end() && s2_it != s2.end())
    {
        if (s1_it->first == s2_it->first)
        {
            result += s1_it->second * s2_it->second;
            s1_it++:
            s2_it++;
        }
        else if (s1_it->first < s2_it->first)
        {
            s1_it = s1.lower_bound(s2_it->first);
        }
        else
        {
            s2_it = s2.lower_bound(s1_it->first);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I would like to refactor this and `std::set_intersection` seems to be close to what I want as the documentation has [an example using `std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection#Example), but is there a way to get this to work on maps and avoid the intermediate array?

Comment: Check your set object declarations. It seems you mean std::pair as the template argument.

Comment: Also a word about what exactly you expect to do each time you find a matching pair.and each time you don't.

Comment: @tinstaafl I've added some text that describes what I am trying to do.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Oops, I meant to say `map`, not `set`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you're using is already very close to the way that `set_intersect` would be implemented.  I can't see any advantage to creating a new map and iterating over it.

However there were a couple of things with your code I wanted to mention.

If you're going to increment your iterators you shouldn't make them constant.

I would expect that there will be more misses than hits when looking for equivalent elements.  I would suggest having the less than comparisons first:

```
double calcProduct( std::map<int , double> const &s1 , std::map<int , double> const &s2 )
{
    auto  s1_it = s1.begin();
    auto  s2_it = s2.begin();

    double result = 0;
    while ( s1_it != s1.end() && s2_it != s2.end() )
    {
        if ( s1_it->first < s2_it->first )
        {
            s1_it = s1.lower_bound( s2_it->first );
        }
        else if(s2_it->first < s1_it->first )
        {
            s2_it = s2.lower_bound( s1_it->first );
        }
        else
        {
            result += s1_it->second * s2_it->second;
            s1_it++;
            s2_it++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The `const` iterator was a typo, sorry. Looking at the numbers, the average number of times round the loop is about 1,000 per call, with just 1% being matches, so I'll try your suggestion.